# Proxy in electron

Tags: proxy, electron

i'm having an electron app through which i am trying to call an url from the same network, but for some security reasons i considered the idea of using a proxy.

```
 function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false },
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
  });

  mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules: "https=192.168.3.242:8000" }, function () {
     mainWindow.loadURL('https://localhost:8000/');
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

but this does not seem to do the trick. Is my idea valid? Any idea what am i doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: I looks your are trying to access the localhost on your proxy server.

Comment: yes, this is what i want to do, but does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

For the whole app, you can use command line switches supported by Electron :

```
const { app } = require('electron')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('proxy-server', '172.17.0.2:3128')
app.on('ready', () => {
  // Your code here
})
```

See [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches)